# Install CentOS on MBP 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, unix, dual-boot

I am trying to install CentOS  8 on my 2019 MacBook Pro 2019 with Catalina 10.15.4. I want to dual boot either with Catalina and CentOS.

Steps so far:

1. Partition with 500GB for CentOS
2. Created a bootable USB Stick with CentOS
3. Installed rEFInd

When I press the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> while restarting, I can choose between my normal start volume and the USB Stick.

When I choose the USB,  I receive the message: "That start volume is not verified."

How can I get it to boot CentOS?

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot or are you you trying to boot off the USB installer?  You also say you want to "Dual boot CentOS or Catalina."  Do you mean CentOS *and* Catalina or is Windows somewhere in the picture?  Please take a moment and clarify exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: First, I want to boot off the USB installer, to install CentOS(here is the problem, since my USB stick is not verified). Later on, I want to choose either to boot CentOS or Catalina. So both OS should be on the macbook. Windows not at all. Sorry for the unclear infos.

Comment: I think @DavidAnderson meant this link:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330  You have to enable booting from External Media.

Comment: @Allan, yes I did that as well.

Comment: I tried the same USB-Stick on a MacbookAir 2013 with Mojave and had no problems(When restarting I could boot from the stick and it was showed me the screen to install CentOS).

Comment: after choosing the EFI, MBP starts the Boot Recovery system and bringt up the message: "The start volume is not verified" and I have to choose my normal HDD Macintosh

Answer (score 1):

You can not install CentOS on the internal drive because CentOS does not have a driver needed to access the internal drive. AFAIK, drivers only exists for macOS and Windows. The Windows driver is part of the Window Support Software which can be downloaded from Apple by using the Boot Camp Assistant. The startup manager rEFInd is an exception, because rEFInd uses UEFI based drivers.

You could try installing CentOS to an external drive.

Comment: But Ubuntu should work for sure?
And why then can I install CentOS then on the other mac with Mojave?